# Aggregating Data Using SUMIFS

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

This follows up a query raised in May, as I have a slightly different problem to the one that Scott Craner kindly answered at the time. [Here's the previous post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56065097/aggregating-data-using-index-match-match-or-sumifs)

Keeping the same examples but adding further information, I would like to summarise the column data on the sheet "Firm Cost Summary" by teams, i.e. there are now multiple column matches that should be added together, not just a single one:
[image: []

This is now being summarised on a different sheet called "Total Business Costs":

[image: []

So what I would like to achieve is to sum every row of table one where column B matches the contents of column A in the second table, but only where row 3 of the first table matches row 4 of the second table. So cell B8 of the second table should add every row labelled Overheads from every column labelled Marketing.

The formula I'm using is as follows (using the example from cell B8 of the second image):

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX('Firm Cost Summary'!$E:$EM,0,MATCH(B$4,'Firm Cost Summary'!$E$3:$EM$3,0)),'Firm Cost Summary'!$B:$B,$A8)
```

That works just fine when there is only one match result, but falls over where there is more than one (e.g. for the Marketing team in the example).

Can anyone suggest anything that will make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to switch to SUMPRODUCT and limit references to the data set:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Firm Cost Summary'!$B6:$B250=$A8)*('Firm Cost Summary'!$E$3:$EM$3=B$4),'Firm Cost Summary'!$E6:$EM250)
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your super speedy response. That works in my small example above, but in reality, the table of data is B6:B250 for the cost codes, E3:EM3 for the departments and the numbers are E6:EM250. I've tried amending your formula but am getting a #N/A error. Can you help?

`=SUMPRODUCT(('Firm Cost Summary'!$B6:$B250=$A8)*('Firm Cost Summary'!$E$3:$EM$3=B$4),'Firm Cost Summary'!$E6:$EM250)`

Comment: @Wincelow make sure there are no errors in the data and no text.

Comment: Thanks Scott, there was a data error in the formula that assigned the department code to people. Now working!

Comment: @Wincelow please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.